# Pre populate jquery token-input values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-tokeninput

In my page I am reading back the data stored in a table. I have two `textboxfor` in the page which is attached with jQuery input token plugin. Once the page is viewed the data is coming and plugin is get attached but once the plugin get attached the existing values inside the boxes are losing and it become blank. Still the plugin is working.

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, new { data_code = Json.Encode(new { id = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, name = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code }), @class = "diag" })               
            </td> 
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_desc, new { @class = "diag_desc" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_level, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".diag").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis","Preapproval")", {
        theme: 'facebook',
        preventDuplicates: true,
        searchingText: 'Searching diagnosis code...',
        tokenLimit: 1,
        hintText: 'Diagnosis Code'
    });
});
```

What is the reason behind the code inside the text box is losing? Am I missing any particular code.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, new { data_code = Json.Encode( new { id = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, name = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code }), @class = "diag" })
```

this is where I am trying to bring back the value for token input using `data_*` attribute of HTML5.

**Edited**

the input token has two attribute id,name. The name attribute is the display text and id value is the one which will pass to the controller during submit.
So if id and name are same value it is working fine with below answer of.

How to achieve the scenario if display value and the value to submit is different. ie. eg: text to shown is 'XYZ' but the while submiting the value to submit is '123'

Comment: Not familiar with `tokenInput` from the [documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), do you need to initially include the current value - `$(".diag").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis","Preapproval")", { prePopulate: [{id:1, name: 'someValue' }], theme: .....)};`?

Comment: @stephenmuecke i can't use prepopulate in jquery bcos it depends on the number of record in the model `m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code`

Comment: But does using `prePopulate` actually show a value initially?

Comment: @stephenmuecke yes it will show the name value in the textbox..in ur code it will be 'somevalue'

Comment: So therefore it should just be a matter of constructing the correct values based on each item in the model. I assume `tokenLimit: 1,` means you can only select one item, so your `TextBoxFor()` method should be `new { data-code="Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code" }` and then `prePopulate: [{id:$(this).data('code'), name: $(this).data('code' }]` (although you may need to do this using `$.each()`

Comment: @stephenmuecke sorry i didn't got u..im naive in jquery :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82030/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is no need to include the `new { data_code = Json.Encode( new { id = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, name = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code })` in the `TextBoxFor()` helper since all you need is the `value` of the element. It can be just

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, new { @class = "diag" })
```

Next to pre-select a value, you need to use the `prePopulate` option of `tokenInput` to set the `id` and `name` properties to initially display. You script needs to be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.diag').each(function() {
    $(this).tokenInput('@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis","Preapproval")', {
      prePopulate: [{id:$(this).val(), name: $(this).val()}],
      theme: 'facebook',
      preventDuplicates: true,
      searchingText: 'Searching diagnosis code...',
      tokenLimit: 1,
      hintText: 'Diagnosis Code'
    });
  });
});
```

The `$.each()` function loops through each textbox and attaches the plugin to it and populates it with a token based on the value of the `diagnosis_code` property.

**Edit**

Based on the edit to the question, if you need to post back one value (which should be the value of `diagnosis_code` property, but want to display a different text value based on another model property,then you would need to include a `data-` attribute. For example, if you want the display text to be based on the `diagnosis_desc` property then the helper would be

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code, new { @class = "diag" data_text = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_desc })
```

and modify the script to

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.diag').each(function() {
    $(this).tokenInput('@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis","Preapproval")', {
      prePopulate: [{id:$(this).val(), name: $(this).data('text')}], // modify this
      ....
```

Comment: the `data_text = "Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_desc" })`should be with out quotes `data_text = Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_desc })` working fine thanks a lot